# Java how to simulate a light on or off?

Tags: java

I tried to simulate a light switch being turned off and on.
Having switch1, switch2 & switch3

I have to Create a Device class which has attributes(name:string and boolean:state ), a method with a constructor(to set up name and set state to false).

I have to change the state of the device from on to off and vice versa and toString that will display the name of the switch and whether the light is on or off.

I also have to create another class that has the main method and it instantiate 3 light switch object(s1,s2&s3).

```java
public class Device {
    private String name;
    private Boolean state;

    public Device(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.state = false;
    }

    public void change_state() {
        if(this.state == on) {
            state = true;
        } else {
            state = false;
        }
    }

    public void on() {
        this.state = true;
    }

    public void off() {
        this.state = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  It would help if you can describe specifically what isn't working at this time.  Is your code producing an error?  Is a specific operation producing an unexpected result?  What specifically has you stuck at this time?  For tips and information on how to ask a question, please read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all : you need to use (true) in change_state() methode  instead of on because "on" in java is not boolean

```
public void change_state() {
        if(this.state == true) {
            state = true;
        } else {
            state = false;
        }
    }
```

after you need to override the default toString methode of Device class

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("name: "+this.name + "/status: " + this.state);
    }
```

finally you can print your result :

```
  public static void main(String []args){
        Device s1 = new Device("S1");
        s1.on();
        Device s2 = new Device("S2");
        s2.off();
        Device s3 = new Device("S3");
        s3.on();
        System.out.println(s1.toString());
        System.out.println(s2.toString());
        System.out.println(s3.toString());
    }
```

your print is :

```
name: S1/status: true
name: S2/status: false
name: S3/status: true
```

Answer (score 2):

State change can look very easy. Also I'd use primitive types wherever possible, not the object version unless there's some good reasons to do so.

Also in Java CamelCase notation is the de facto coding standard.

```
...
boolean state = true;
...
    public void change_state() {
        this.state == !this.state;
    }
```

If you wish you can also return state directly while changing:

```
    public boolean changeState() {
        this.state = !this.state;
        return this.state;
    }
```

Instead of on/off methods you can also return the value and use only one call - like a 'real' button:

```
    public boolean trigger() {
        this.state == !this.state;
        return this.state;
    }
```

I'd not use toString method application code as it get's dirty code pretty easy. If you like to get the name of the device do it the clean way using a getter:

```
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
```

Benefit is many frameworks hold up to this getter/setter standard and you can make use of if later on without code changes. Also no dev will look at toString if he wants to access the name.